# Cross-browser curved borders

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the best way to achieve cross-browser(ff,ie>6,chrome,opera,safari) curved corners on a div. I found this article http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers and I've followed instructions step by step multiple times, here is my css :

```
#content_wrapper{
    -moz-border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color:#F2DADC;
    border:25px solid #ECD3D5;
    height:780px;
    opacity:0.7;
    width:747px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    zoom:1;
}

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style>
#content_wrapper{
behavior: url(template/css/border-radius.htc);
border-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Can somebody point me what am I doing wrong or is there a better way to achieve the same effect, its working in all browsers except in IE

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If that's an unmodified snippet from your HTML file, it's clear why it doesn't work: You're using a `<style>` tag within another `<style>`.

As a first test, just try replacing your entire snippet with (remove the IE specific block!):

```
#content_wrapper{
    -moz-border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
    behavior: url(template/css/border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color:#F2DADC;
    border:25px solid #ECD3D5;
    height:780px;
    opacity:0.7;
    width:747px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    zoom:1;
}
```

If that works, you can move the IE specific parts into a separate `<style>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
#content_wrapper{
    -moz-border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color:#F2DADC;
    border:25px solid #ECD3D5;
    height:780px;
    opacity:0.7;
    width:747px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    zoom:1;
}
</style>


<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
#content_wrapper{
    behavior: url(template/css/border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

If you still have problems, try the example zip file from the google website: http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius-demo.zip

Answer (score 8):

You could put **[JQuery Curvy Corners](http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html)** to use to do it all out of the box instead.

Comment: Sure, use JavaScript for styling purposes... what a terrible piece of advice.

Comment: @Seb: If there was a better cross-browser solution, this would not have existed in the first place.

Comment: @Sarfaz do you know how many JS solutions are out there for things not requiring it? The fact that it exists doesn't mean there's not a better solution. In fact, look at the correct solution in this question.

Answer (score 3):

A citation from the article you mentioned:

> The path to border-radius.htc works differently than you may expect—unlike background-image paths which are relative to the stylesheet, this path is relative to the page from which you call the CSS.
>
> That’s why it’s a good idea to avoid relative paths like we did above.

Answer (score 2):

Download the `.htc` file:

- http://curved-corner.googlecode.com/files/border-radius.htc

and put that inside the folder `./template/css`. See the http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/ project for detail (as linked from the article you've placed).

Comment: Download this backdoor and put it into your windows directory.

Comment: I did download it, but its not working again, did you try this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the css:

```
.curved {

 -moz-border-radius:10px;

 -webkit-border-radius:10px;

 behavior:url(border-radius.htc);

}
```

And here is how you would use it, of course:

```
<div class="curved">Curvd div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you interested in getting rounded corners in IE, this may be of use - http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 0):

hello i am going to just be lazy and paste a link to someone elses work.... I dont want the bounty

try this one.
http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/