# What is the best way to create rounded borders that are cross browser compatible?

Tags: html, rounded-corners, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-browser curved borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795097/cross-browser-curved-borders)

I would like to create divs and other elements that will contain designed borders. The borders will be basic CSS ready borders. While I can code it, I want to know the best method and process for making the rounded-borders attribute cross browser compatible. (At least among the  largely accepted browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari). Any pointers?

Comment: you can have a look on this http://www.curvycorners.net/

Comment: http://border-radius.com/ generates CSS with all necessary prefixes. Can use it as a reference.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/css-rounded-corners this one as well

Answer (score 0):

```
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
```

[Source](http://siglingsoftware.blogspot.ca/2012/05/css-rounded-corners-for-all-major.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `border-radius` property is already supported in Internet Explorer (from version 9 up), Firefox (version 4 up), Chrome, Safari and Opera. However, if you want to be sure you can use something like this:

```
.border-radius {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this helpful site
http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/
It has explanations and working examples
Also take a look at W3C advice. Very helpful
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-shaping