# How can i make some curve to the border of a container by css?

Tags: css

I have not enough reputation to post images.
I want to make a container like this but i cant google something like that http://postimg.org/image/dibumt2zb/.
thank you all!

Comment: What's your approach? Did you try anything before asking apart from googleing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-browser curved borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795097/cross-browser-curved-borders)

Answer (score 1):

Try in the css:

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

You can also make:

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

if you want a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```css
.someclass
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:5px solid #000;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass"> </div>
```

Comment: Your welcome in stackoverflow